# ESP8266 - Sonoff POW - Reading HLW8012

Tags: timer, arduino, esp8266, interrupt-handling

I am using this library (https://github.com/SensorsIot/Sonoff-POW) and it is working very good, however from time to time I get an Exception and the sonoff reboots.

I have implemented a simple sketch which reads the power values and sends them using a webclient. The webclient parts works perfectly without the POWER code so I presume it might be related to an interrupt from the POWER library

This is the stack error shown in the serial monitor...

connecting to xxxxx.xxx.me

```
Exception 0: Illegal instruction
Decoding 29 results
0x402034f4: ESP8266PowerClass::measureVoltageFreq() at C:\Users\Sergio\Documents\SERGIO\libraries\Sonoff_POW-master/power.cpp line 294
0x40107018: interrupt_handler at C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.3.0\cores\esp8266/core_esp8266_wiring_digital.c line 119
0x4010177d: ppEnqueueRxq at ?? line ?
0x40101433: ppProcessTxQ at ?? line ?
0x40106fe0: interrupt_handler at C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.3.0\cores\esp8266/core_esp8266_wiring_digital.c line 113
0x40103d19: lmacProcessTXStartData at ?? line ?
0x4010707c: interrupt_handler at C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.3.0\cores\esp8266/core_esp8266_wiring_digital.c line 135
0x401055c1: ets_timer_disarm at ?? line ?
0x40106fe0: interrupt_handler at C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.3.0\cores\esp8266/core_esp8266_wiring_digital.c line 113
0x4020954c: pm_get_sleep_type at ?? line ?
0x40105b26: spi_flash_read at ?? line ?
0x401074b8: pvPortZalloc at C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.3.0\cores\esp8266/heap.c line 33
0x4020901d: pm_set_sleep_time at ?? line ?
0x402094b2: pm_get_sleep_type at ?? line ?
0x4020955f: pm_get_sleep_type at ?? line ?
0x4021ac3d: ets_timer_handler_isr at ?? line ?
0x4021ac82: ets_timer_handler_isr at ?? line ?
```

The reboot always happens in this code:

```
Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.print(host);

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
   WiFiClient client;
  // const int httpPort = 80;
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("....connection failed");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("....connected!");
```

Right after the I see the print in the serial port of"connecting to host" message, but I dont get the print "connected."

Is there any chance the library is doing something during the "client.connect" which causes the exception:

> Exception Causes (EXCCAUSE) EXCCAUSE Code Cause Name  Cause
>   Description   Required Option EXCVADDR Loaded
>
> 0 IllegalInstructionCause Illegal instruction Exception   No

I dont expect to review the whole library, but maybe some guidance on why this might be happening.
maybe I can detach the interrupts during the client request?
maybe implement some code to stop this timer and then call it again? (i dont know how to do this)

extracted from the library:

```
void ESP8266PowerClass::startMeasure(void)
{
    os_timer_setfn(&myTimer, (os_timer_func_t *)&ESP8266PowerClass::timerCallback, NULL);
    os_timer_arm(&myTimer, 1, true);  // every ms
}
```

thank you for your help